# HTTP GETS don't complete when loading sample polymer app in DART editor

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

Following Steps

File-New Application

Select  Web Application( Using Polymer Library)

Right click HTML file and select "Run in Dartium"

Browser never loads entire app

Looking at network tab in JS console of browser
Random files fail to load (Get never completes)
Each time you refresh the browser it is a different set of files that fail

Comment: sounds like you are running the polymer element rather then the containing html.

Comment: I guess nobody saw your question because it missed the dart tag.
I had a similar behavior recently with a specific Dart version but that was an exception. Normally this works fine.